# What exactly are the square images generated from Encryption?

Tags: cryptography

i.e. `GenerateDerivedKey[]` or `Encrypt[]` gives you a byte array with an 8 by 8 color grid that seems to represents a unique code generated by the encrypting function. I tried to save the image with `Export[]` or `Export/ImportByteArray[]` but outputs either `$failed` or just a bare screen capture of the function text. `Image[]` says it needs to be a 3 by 3 matrix to apply colors I guess?
So what is this and how is it supposed to be exported?

Comment: I am not sure that the graphic *means* anything per se. You can get the generated key using `key = GenerateDerivedKey["yourPWD", "yourSalt"]; key["DerivedKey"]`. The result is a `ByteArray` object.

Comment: There only seem to be 4 colors in the image so it is effectively a 8 by 8 array of 2 bit binary numbers so it isn't going to have all the information contained in the 64,  8 bit, numbers in the key ByteArray.